# Plotting concatenated pandas dateframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have data in the following format:

```
                            age       height     weight     
name1        2011-09-13     21        178        75
             2010-09-13     20        178        80
                            age       height     weight   
name2        2011-09-13     15        130        42
             2010-09-13     14        124        39
```

for mobile viewers:

[image: format_image]

I created this format by concat(dataframe, keys=names) and there will be multiple names and dates in this format.

I want to be able to pick one (or more) names and graph one of the parameters where x-axis will be date and y-axis e.g. weight. Is the only way to repeat name1 for each date or there is a simpler way to graph it? I was attempting to do it in matplotlib initially.

Thank you very much for your help!

edit: example code

```
import pandas as pd
import collections
import datetime 

dictionary = {'name1': {str(datetime.date(2016, 5, 5)): {"age": 21, "height": 178, "weight": 75}, str(datetime.date(2016, 5, 4)): {"age": 20, "height": 178, "weight": 80}},'name2': {str(datetime.date(2016, 5, 5)): {"age": 15, "height": 130, "weight": 42}, str(datetime.date(2016, 5, 4)): {"age": 14, "height": 124, "weight": 39}}}
ordered_final = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(dictionary.items()))

names = []
alld = []

for name, c in ordered_final.iteritems():
    names.append(name)
    alld.append(pd.DataFrame.from_dict(c, orient='index'))

concat = pd.concat(alld, keys=names)
```

It is highly likely that there is a better way to store this data as a date frame however, than what I use currently.

Comment: Could you add some code (sample data, your best effort) so that people can easily start from this to help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure columns `age`, `height`, `weight` are twice or more times in one `DataFrame`?

Comment: @jezrael Thank you, I have edited the post to include the code. It might be the case that there exists a better way of transforming this dictionary to pandas that would make plotting easier

Comment: @Dilettant thank you, I included the code.

Comment: pd.set_option('display.multi_sparse', False)
    weights =  concat['weight']

    chart =  weights['name1']

    import matplotlib.dates as mdates

    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%Y'))
    plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
    chart.plot(style=['o','rx'])

I have included something like this for now but there is probably a better way to go about it.